# Paperclip less memory in background job without activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, beanstalkd

I use resque to process pictures and upload to s3 with paperclip in background. But every worker will load whole rails instance about 120MB~150MB.

I found this tutorial could deal with background job without loading rails.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/243-beanstalkd-and-stalker

How could I manipulate paperclip with stalker, or the other better solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Paperclip is dependent on ActiveRecord. You can always omit the controller and view environment components, though.

Comment: @tadman I have no idea how to manipulate paperclip without model. Could you give me some tips or code, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I made a lightweight class that can be used for Paperclip.

That a look a it here : [gist](https://gist.github.com/basgys/5712426)